# SharePoint 2013 - deactivate controls on .htm custom page layouts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I currently have the following snipet loading from my custom page layout...

```
<!--CS: Start Create Snippets From Custom ASP.NET Markup Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@ Register TagPrefix="Claims" Namespace="WebPartsAndControls" Assembly="WebPartsAndControls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e2637de7f0074503" %>-->
```

...which controls several other Claim tags on the same page below it (i.e.)

```
<!--MS:<Claims:FirstNameClaim runat="server" />-->
```

I have a developer who may need to go in debug mode to modify this Claims control.  When that happens, is there anyway to tell SharePoint to stop reading this control, while my developer is working on this item? and then enable it again when he tells me it is ready?  Problem is that while he is working on this control in visual studio, front-end SharePoint pages generate errors.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option available. The best option I can think of is to edit those page and close the webpart. Once completed you can open it.

Also its not a good idea to debug while users are on the system. Usually we have log statements which tells us what is wrong. Then we take that information and fix it in the development box. During off business hours deploy and confirm the fix.